# Ruta EP (Eclipse Plugin) - Script changes not triggering updates in Descriptor folder until Clean

Tags: eclipse, uima, ruta

I have noticed the following behavior in UIMA Ruta Eclipse Plugin:

I've imported an existing Maven project into Eclipse workspace using the POM file to populate the project and dependencies. I have the UIMA Ruta Eclipse plugin installed. The project I copied was such a project, so it has the `descriptor`,  `script`, `resources` folders and all three were in `git`.

Once project was imported, I went to the Ruta perspective and did `UIMA Ruta -> Convert...` and `UIMA Ruta -> Update project` for good measure.

Well, it no longer automatically generates files in my `descriptor` folder upon updating them or creating them in `script`. (It has never automatically deleted files after deleting them from `script`, but that's another story).

I've been watching my `Eclipse` project files to see if they were different from my source `Eclipse` project files before and after updating using the `UIMA Ruta -> Convert...` option.

It did some stuff to my `.buildpath` file, which now looks like this on both the original and the clone:

```
<buildpath>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="script">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="ruta" value="script"/>
        </attributes>
    </buildpathentry>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="descriptor">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="ruta" value="descriptor"/>
        </attributes>
    </buildpathentry>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="ruta" value="resources"/>
        </attributes>
    </buildpathentry>
</buildpath>
```

Now, if I clean and then it builds automatically, the `descriptor` folder does get populated and updated. But only after a clean, and sometimes it takes more than one, because sometimes the clean errors out with a message indicating that it could not delete some of the files in `target`. If I uncheck build automatically, and then clean (no auto-build after clean), and then build, it works every time without error.

Any idea how to address this problem, and crucially, **how can I configure the Eclipse plugin's Ruta build behaviors?**

Comment: Can you add the error message about the delletion problem in target? With this buildpath configuration, the ruta plugin should not  do anything in the target folder.

Comment: I strongly recommend to use the ruta-maven-plugin if the ruta script/descriptors/resources are maanaged and developed in a maven-based project. This plugin also automatically generates the buildpath file.